# What does mean METRICEU?

Tags: sql, oracle, dmp

I have some codes.

I think this codes are related with dump files(.dmp).

I can not analyse this code.

I want to know what this code means.

Especially, about METRICEU.

```
METRICSUsynonyms
METRICEU 0
METRICSUviews
CREATE VIEW "VW_OPERRIGHT" ("VCID","OPERATORID","FUNCTIONID") AS 
?select vcid,operatorid,functionid from cc_operright
union
select  distinct a.vcid,a.operatorid,b.functionid from cc_operrole 
a,cc_roleright b where a.roleid=b.roleid 

CREATE VIEW "VW_AGENTRESTDETAIL"      ("VCID","AGENTID","OPERNAME","AGENTPHONE","GROUPID","CLUSTERID","GROUPNAME"," APPLYTIME","CANCELTIME","AGREETIME","AUDITORNAME","AUDITORID","LEAVESTARTTIME","LEAVEENDTIME","LEAVETIMELEN","AGREELEN","APPLYRESULT","RESTMODE") AS select ard.vcid, ard.agentid,op.opername, ard.agentphone,
... ...
METRICEU 2
METRICSUstored procedures
ALTER SESSION SET "_LOAD_WITHOUT_COMPILE" = PLSQL
ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL = 2 NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = 'BYTE'        PLSQL_CODE_TYPE = 'INTERPRETED' PLSQL_DEBUG = TRUE PLSQL_WARNINGS = 'DISABLE:ALL'PLSQL_CCFLAGS = ''
CREATE FORMAT71 PROCEDURE "PR_JUDGERIGHT" 
? CREATE  procedure pr_judgeright(
+     apprvcid        integer,  
+     approperid      integer,  
+     checkedvcid     integer,  
)     checkedoperid   integer,  
9     retflag out     integer,  
*     retmsg  out     varchar2,  
1     url     out     varchar2   
 ) is v_count integer;
... ...
TABLE "NGCC_RECORD_WAY"
ANALCOMPUTE TS "NGCC_RECORD_WAY" ANALYZE  TABLE "NGCC_RECORD_WAY"     ESTIMATE STATISTICS 
TABLE "RECTEMPLATE"
ANALCOMPUTE TS "RECTEMPLATE" ANALYZE  TABLE "RECTEMPLATE"  ESTIMATE    STATISTICS 
TABLE "TBL_114CALL"
ANALCOMPUTE TS "TBL_114CALL" ANALYZE  TABLE "TBL_114CALL"  ESTIMATE  STATISTICS 
TABLE "TBL_114CALL_BAK"
ANALCOMPUTE TS "TBL_114CALL_BAK" ANALYZE  TABLE "TBL_114CALL_BAK"    ESTIMATE STATISTICS 
ENDTABLE
METRICEU 287
METRICEUG0
EXIT
EXIT
```

Comment: What, exactly, are you posting here?  Normally, a dmp file is a binary file in a proprietary format generated by the Oracle export utility (classic or DataPump).  Are you saying that you have such a dump file and that, you've maybe tried opening it in a text editor or run `strings` on it?  You aren't meant to analyze the contents of this sort of dump file, you're just meant to import it into an Oracle database using the import utility (classic or DataPump).

Comment: How did you create this "dump" file. As Justin said it is most definitely not created by one of the Oracle tools.

Comment: @JustinCave This is the typical output when running `string` on a dump file. AFAIK, the dump format is not publicity documented. So I vote to close as "primarily opinion-based [...] this answer tends to be almost entirely based on opinion *not facts and references*"

Comment: What is your question?  How exactly do you expect us to help you?  A dump file is not a program.

Comment: My question is to know what this code means.

Comment: Thank you for your kind helpings. I solved this problem on base of your asks.